# ATI Hybrid Graphics Over Heat. Intel GPU not working!

Tags: ati, graphics, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, gpu

I just followed this guide (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) and installed the proprietary ATI drivers on my laptop which have ATI Hybrid Graphics (ATI Radeon HD 6770 M GPU). It worked and the GPU is working well. But it started to heatup. Any way to fix this?

I switched to the Intel GPU through the control panel and then, after entering the password in the login screen, nothing comes.. Only the wallpaper. But Unity 2D works. Before trying the guide, I used only the Intel GPU (never installed the ATI drivers) and with that setup, Unity 3D worked. (But had some tiny lags. But its ok). Why is it not working now? How to fix this? If I can fix the heating issue, I don't need to try the Intel GPU.

PS : Specially, the CPU temperature goes up while using the ATI GPU. When using only the Intel GPU, it didn't went up like this!

Comment: This seems odd to me. My HD6770 runs much cooler with the Catalyst proprietary driver than the radeon open source driver, by about 15-20 C. But I will do some research and see if I can find a way to force it to run cooler with Catalyst.

Comment: @Tim Thanks my friend... Are you running pure Ubuntu? Do you use Unity? Did you install the additional drivers or got it from the ATI site? Whats the exact temperature? In my case, its about 55C ... Its a bit normal but the problem is, I can feel that when typing. Its feels like its over heating. But in Windows, it stay in 49C

Comment: My actual temperature in Ubuntu is from 44 to 52 C, depending on the load. I am using Unity. My driver is the one installed via Additional Hardware Drivers applet, but it is maintained by apt when new releases come to the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: I've had the same problem and so far the Andrikos PPA is the only thing that has worked for me. See http://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517