# Can't install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10

Tags: ati, hybrid-graphics

I have a laptop with ATI Radeon 6770M HD Hybrid graphics card. In Ubuntu 12.04, I installed the fglrx driver through "additional drivers" and it worked. (I can even switch GPUs). But in the new Ubuntu 12.10, after installing, Unity won't load.

Only the mouse and the wallpaper. If I initialize the settings `sudo aticonfig --initial` then after rebooting it gives a warning saying I'm in low graphics mode! How to fix this?

Earlier I used software source to install the drivers. But when using the terminal, I got this warning :

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
```

Update : Filed a bug report in launchpad : https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661

Comment: Just filed a bug report : https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661

Comment: I believe this issue is because the ATI drivers do not yet support the current X Server 1.13.  So we are going to be waiting on ATI.

Comment: I've just added my comments to that bug report. I find it somewhat shocking that a bug like this made it through to final, as ATI cards are not that rare...

Comment: AMD released a special 12.9 beta driver that would work with the xserver 1.13 in 12.10: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst129betadriver.aspx; however, this doesn't seem to have been packaged into the default repository yet. Also, it only supports HD 5000 or later cards: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-12-10-quantal-fglrx-legacy-12-6-unsupported-wh

Comment: @AndrewMao Tried that beta driver and it also failed :(

Comment: AMD released a new driver 12.10, but that still hasn't fixed the problem. Just reporting in to save people the heart ache...

Comment: some hd radeon cards are not supported in 12.10 release so you have to install legasy ati driver not a newest one.For those who have hd 2xxx-4xxx cards check this link http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html

Comment: @EApubs I actually got my HD7870 to work yesterday.

At login screen:
CTRL+ALT+F1 && Login && sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Guys, please add this information in either answers or add it to existing answers, information should be posted there, not buried in comments!

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I started with a clean 12.10 install (not an upgrade)
My card is a Radeon HD 5450

First thing I done was to install Linux-source and Linux headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

I noticed that many with Nvidia cards were having to do this and am sure I saw mentioned some-where that it also helped ATI users.

Like everyone else if I installed either of the proprietary drivers after reboot I was able to login but lost unity.

One thing I did notice is that installing the driver did not install Catalyst control centre (not sure if it is the same for everyone else)

So I installed Synaptic package manager and installed fglrx-updates from there

[image]

Now the Catalyst control centre was installed.

Upon rebooting however instead of being able to login with no Unity the system was hanging at the splash screen.

So I applied `nomodeset` and this time it booted with Unity present

Here is the result of fglrxinfo

[image]

And here is what software sources says

[image]

With `nomodeset` applied I might not be getting the splash screen on boot up but fglrx-updates is working well. I would go as far as to say that it is performing better than it was in 12.04

**More info**

Grub offers me 2 kernels

3.5.0-18-generic
and
3.5.0-17-generic

The later one '18' is good, the older one '17' still loads without Unity

Comment: On a just-installed Ubuntu 12.10 I installed `linux-headers-generic`, `fgrlx-updates` and `fgrlx-amdcccle-updates` then restarted and the driver (including Catalyst Control Center) have been installed. I didn't `nomodeset`, but unlike you, I didn't try to install the proprietary driver before.

Comment: @Zippoxer perhaps you could add this information to this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661  It may help others and help get the bug sorted quicker.

Comment: Can't apply 'nomodeset' or it doesn't help. I've added nomodeset to boot by this instruction http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 but still getting hanged splash screen. How to fix it?

Comment: This has worked for me on an HD5450. I previously tried so many other guides without success. I had `linux-source` and `linux-headers-generic` already installed so I didn't have to this time. I followed your instructions and everything is working perfectly. However, I didn't have to do apply `monodeset`.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @Jean-Louis `nomodeset`, not `monodeset`. Sadly, I've tried this advice but even with nomodeset my unity is gone and my terminal doesn't work. Messed up.

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Answer (score 7):

For those who have hybrid systems (ATI/intel) and fglrx has stopped working in 12.10, then the problem might be like the one described here (fglrx incompatibility with the recent version of the intel driver):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1068404

What I would suggest would be

1. Remove all the fglrx* packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
   ```
2. Add my PPA in your repositories list:

   > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrikos
3. Update your package information:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Update the `fglrx` and `intel` drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx xserver-xorg-video-intel
   ```
5. Don't forget to enable the `fglrx` driver

   ```
   sudo aticonfig --initial --force
   ```

Comment: Hi Nick,

I tried your solution by unfortunately it didn't work out for me. Also i am wondering if the command under 4. should be sudo aticonfig --initial? I also could not find the command under the aticonfig man pages; see http://man.cx/aticonfig(1)

Comment: Yes davorao, it is initial, I'm fixing it now. What system do you have? This solution is for the hybrid ATI/intel under ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Hi Nick, my system is a Intel HD3000 acting as the integrated GPU with a Radeon HD 6490M as the discrete GPU. The Laptop in question is the Samsung Chronos 7 700z3a-S03-DE. I have tried the using the xserver-xorg-video-intel deb from your PPA but couldn't manage to get it working.

Comment: I tried this solution. It worked. But I have nasty "AMD testing only" box and (not sure if connected, but very probable) my mouse hangs sometimes and sometimes also with keyboards - especially when selecting something in unity bar. Do you think it's connected? More stable solution would be better!

Comment: I would believe this is another bug. If my solution worked for you, could you please vote it up so that more people see it?

Thanks

Comment: Nick, sorry to bother. Just updated to the 12.10 to discover the horrible intel/ATI problem. lcpci -k | grep 'ATI' lists Radeon HD 4870 for me, and it used to work fine with the 12.6 version of the drivers. When I boot w/o fglrx, I just get a desktop wallpaper w/ nothing. Terminal won't even open. So I hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 and tried your fixed version. However, when I run aticonfig --initial --force, it gives me "no supported adapters detected". What can I do to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind, Nick. For now, I went around this by using Tomasz Makarewicz's ppa repository to downgrade to xorg 1.12 and set up the legacy fglrx. Hope the fix for xorg 1.13 + fglrx-legacy comes out soon! Thanks for your help for this issue so far.

Comment: +1 This answer solved [my overheating problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225631/ouch-laptop-running-super-hot-after-12-10-upgrade) too!

Comment: @Algomorph
Radeon HD 4870 is not supported any more with the latest fglrx drivers. You will need to downgrade to xorg 1.12 and use older drivers (or just use the open source ones)

Comment: when i add repository it says `cannot add PPA:'ppa:andrikos'` &  `Please check that the PPA name or format is correct`

Comment: if i try to remove that with `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:andrikos` and it gives the same error :/

Answer (score 4):

I went to terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for example) and did :

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
```

Now my computer is pretty slow but a least I can use it and wait for the problem to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. On upgrade of Ubuntu 12.04 -> Ubuntu 12.10, the contents of lightdm.conf in `/etc/lightdm/` are completely erased. Installing or reconfiguring lightdm does NOT install this file here, so lightdm does not know how to go about displaying itself. You must do the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop && sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

insert the following text:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
```

Save the file via CTRL + X and sudo reboot. You may not have to uninstall fglrx, but I do not know.

Comment: can you please tell us the steps you followed? Installed fglrx from the additional drivers and installed gdm?

Comment: sudo apt-get purge fglrx lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop && revised contents above on how to configure lightdm.

Comment: one small problem... just recognized that you have updated from ubuntu 12.04. Im on a new installation

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Go to [amd.com](http://amd.com) and download their latest beta driver (which was just updated to 12.11). Run and install.

Please note that the stable driver will not work with unity.

Then head here to get a script to remove the watermark: http://areyoueye.net/?p=187

Slainte!

Comment: Hi @ryanpcmcquen do you have a pure AMD/ATI graphics card or do you have an Intel one working as the integrated besides the AMD/ATI discrete. I'm finding that for those with only AMD/ATI cards your solution with the new AMD Catalyst 12.11 drivers does work, but for those with an added Intel integrated card this doesn't provide the solution.

Comment: I have the A8, so no Intel.

Comment: This worked for me with the Radeon HD 5670.

Comment: Using the beta driver was the only solution that actually worked on my system, also using a single Radeon HD card.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug at this time with fglrx-installer and Ubuntu 12.10

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1025488

I always say **"search for open and confirmed bugs"** before you proceed with something, especially when the distribution is new released.

You can participate to this bug if affects you ,by posting comments there and click the button "Yes it affects me" (you have to have a Launchpad account).

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me:

1. remove current fglrx
   `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh`
   `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*`
2. add ppa repository
   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:andrikos/ppa`
3. update packages list
   `sudo apt-get update`
4. install packages
   `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. May i found a possible solution.
First i opened the Ubuntu-Software-Center and i was looking for "additional drivers". After installing the "additional drivers" i installed the ATI driver and after a reboot my notebook startet normally with unity and with the right propietary driver.

Note: The installation from the Software-Sources-button was not working in my case.

Comment: That would fit in with my solution, could there be something wrong with with the package offered in software sources?

Comment: Didn't worked for me :(