# how to un-install a special driver/kernel in 13.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have tried to install a special ATI driver using a method described in [this Debian help wiki page](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/to-do-list-after-installing-ubuntu-13-04-aka-raring-ringtail-operating-system/)

Details:

> Alternative ATI Legacy Video Driver PPA installation for (for < 5000
>   series cards):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic fglrx-legacy
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

> And then reboot.

There were a couple of warnings at `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic fglrx-legacy` with `update-alternatives`.

But, at the last step I got

```
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

Unity does not start any more. I only can login to GNOME.

How can I get back to a working system?

Comment: no one can point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204428/unity-missing-cant-see-top-or-side-panels):

1. Ran from a Gnome desktop terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge fglrx lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop
   ```
2. Enabled Unity via `ccsm`, and rebooted.
3. After login to Ubuntu desktop, running `ccsm` again to do the settings did the trick.

Now, according to system settings, I have the driver `Gallium 0.4 on ATI RS480`.

Unity is working again. Slow - but working.