# Openstack Ubuntu 14.04 cannot access dashboard after reboot

Tags: openstack, reboot

I am a novice on openstack. I have followed the steps to intell openstack on my Intel based linux box (not on a virtual machine): http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthe...

With "sudo openstack-install --upstream-ppa" after 2 hours, I found all services are up and running, then I was able to login to horizon.

But after reboot the linux and the linux box, I cannot access to horizon any more. Actually, I do not know the proper procedure how to reboot the machine, I just reboot the linux system.

I believe there should a way to shutdown openstack and rejoin the stacks after reboot, which I don't know how. When I checked the "openstack-status", it looks pretty normal and all services are running right after reboot. But I don't really sure they are really running.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it seems like you have disabled Unity. I did the same in Ubuntu 15.04.

If you can see your mouse, right-click to access the terminal, otherwise hit `Ctrl+Alt+t`. From there, enter the following in terminal:

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

then

`setsid unity`

I found this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204428/unity-missing-cant-see-top-or-side-panels). Hope it helps.

P.S. To reboot, type `sudo reboot` or `sudo shutdown -r now`.

Comment: Sorry, it not about the rebooting linux OS, it is related how to restart openstack running on the linux. Thanks anyway.