# Has anyone got an Nvidia 940M to work on 14.04.4 LTS w/ Nvidia proprietary drivers?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I've been trying for a couple of days now to get my 940M to work on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS to no avail (currently stuck on login loop issue), and yet there doesn't appear to be much discussion of issues surrounding the card. I have a feeling that I'm overlooking something simple.

Has anyone else been able to get an Nvidia 940M to run on 14.04.4 LTS with Nvidia's proprietary drivers?

If so, how did you do it?

The nouveau drivers appear to work just fine, but I expect better performance with Nvidia's.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to stick to 14.04.4, which is two years old, for a card which came out in March last year? Try a LiveCD of the latest daily of 16.04LTS - if that works, do a release-upgrade. Changes are cosmetic at the moment, there won't change much until release on April 21.

Comment: 14.04.4 is that old?! I didn't know. I mostly downloaded it because I was advised that it would be a good idea to get the latest LTS distribution. I'm a recent Windows refugee. I will try installing 16.04 and report back!

Comment: 14.04. **4** is an update to the original 14.04 which is two years old. But even with an updated LTS enablement stack, the latest 16.04 with latest **everything** is a better fit for a recent nvidia graphics driver.

Comment: @emk2203 You give really bad advises.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.4 is not old. It has kernel 4.2 and a new graphical stack. It has been released in Feb '16.

Comment: @Pilot6: This would be bad advice if he runs a server. For a single-user laptop with recent hardware, It's certainly better to try a recent distribution just two weeks from release date, instead of making it work with a ppa.

16.04 most certainly detects his graphics hardware correctly, as it did for my `nvidia-prime` system.

Comment: If you really wish to run the proprietary driver, then download it, and install from "recovery mode" (answer yes to all prompts). In case of updates making life hard; reboot into recovery mode and first do `bash NVIDIA...blahblah.run --uninstall` then do an immediate re-install ( `bash NVIDIA...blahblah.run`) .  (Works for me in 14.04.4 with latest all)

Comment: @Hannu: This was actually the last thing I tried before I posted this. It ended up messing up my install to such an extent that I couldn't even boot in low-graphics mode, and so I reinstalled 14.04.4. Uninstalling it didn't help either, by the way.

Comment: @emk2203 Your advice appears to have worked. I installed the latest daily of 16.04 LTS, installed the latest driver that popped up from `ubuntu-drivers`, rebooted, and that was it. `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` shows that the 940M is ready for OpenGL rendering. There was no login loop. Also, `optimus-prime` installed itself with the driver! Last, but not least, the touchpad issues I was having in 14.04.4LTS are gone too. Hurrah! If you want to post an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Redbeardt YMMV then, ... and you have hybrid graphics - you didn't tell about having a laptop (apart from **M** in the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of these and other **hard-ware related** troubles,test the latest, relatively stable liveCD - OP found out that the latest 16.04LTS (close to release candidate, kernel freeze today) not only fixes the graphics issue, but also other issues (touchpad).

After the test is successful, the usual way for existing systems is `update-manager -d` to get the most recent version of Ubuntu or a reinstall if you were testing Ubuntu support on a new hardware system.

Do this *only* if you see a hardware issue. Also, it should be a system with a single user, and not mission-critical. Laptops are prime candidates for this, since they usually have the most pesky hardware issues and the troublemakers inside are not exchangeable.

Downside of running the latest distribution is that in case of other issues, it's difficult to find existing solutions on the net. But you can always come to [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) for that.

Answer (score 3):

You probably did not install `nvidia-prime` for your hybrid graphics.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

If there are any errors, post output to your question. Then reboot.

You can also install a newer driver from a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
```

Both 352 and 361 drivers support Nvidia 940M adapter.

Comment: Actually I had tried this yesterday. It didn't help. :(

Comment: nvidia-361 doesn't work for me but 367 from that ppa. Note that [reset Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204428/unity-missing-cant-see-top-or-side-panels) can be useful after install nvidia-drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer was simply installing a 16.04 LTS daily instead of 14.04.4 LTS, as suggested by @emk2203 in the OP comments!

After booting up the 16.04 LTS, everything went fairly smoothly compared to my stint on 14.04 LTS.