# Ati Radeon 4200 HD Drivers on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, ati, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10)

I searched a lot for the good solution, but none seems to work on 12.10 for this graphical card.

Is there someone yet that found the solution to get this card working with 3d-possibilities?

If yes, please answer so that anyone that has this problem can use the solution...