# Check if my 12.04 has graphics card drivers and find the right ones

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, graphics

How can I check whether my system has a driver for the graphics card installed? And if it hasn't, how can I find which one to install, through the repositories or through other sources? I got Ubuntu 12.04.

I have tried what [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214642/how-to-force-ubuntu-to-re-check-for-graphic-drivers) suggests - I also have ATI Radeon 4500 HD card, or something like that - and I ended up still having nothing showing I do have a driver, plus my Unity 3D became Unity 2D, so I purged fglxr right away.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Open the unity search menu (the button at the top left corner) and search for "drivers" and you will find a driver program that will search for all the drivers required for the hardware in your PC.  (The icon for this program looks like an PCI E device (such as a graphics card or sound card)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `System Settings` in the Unity launcher or at the right top corner of the screen and then go to `Additional Drivers` section.

From there you will be able to install a driver if it is displayed.

[image]

Comment: I did that,and I get nothing. The list is empty and I have no choices, except "Help" and "Close". Enable is grayed out.

Comment: @NoobDoob How old is this card actually? Maybe it's not supported by Ubuntu 12.04. Btw, you can also open a terminal and enter de following command to see your card: lspci | grep VGA

Comment: orestarod@orestis-VAIO:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series]

Comment: The system is from 2009. May you explain what this result means?

Comment: So the card can be seen, but I can't find out whether I have a driver or not, and how to find the right driver.

Comment: The problem with ATI is that they drop support really fast on older cards on Linux, normally the proprietary drivers are available with the additional driver section. It could be that ATI no longer support this card but I'm not so sure about it because I'm using a Nvidia card and no ATI card. Please try the Offical Ubuntu Forums, maybe someone can you help you out with this weird problem, because at the moment I can't. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem. This is what  faced wherever else I was looking at, I was just hoping that by now someone would have found a solution. But since the support for this card probaby is no more, I am seeing myself having a hard time about it. Thank you for your time.