# Mobility Radeon on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati, xorg, radeon

10 ubuntu studio and cannot get my ati radeon mobility 4650 to work.
from lshw:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
```

from lspci:

```
 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
```

from lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
vesafb                 13797  1 
ip6t_REJECT            12574  1  
xt_hl                  12521  6 
ip6t_rt                12558  3 
nf_conntrack_ipv6      14054  7 
nf_defrag_ipv6         13158  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
ipt_REJECT             12541  1 
xt_LOG                 17349  10 
bnep                   18140  2 
xt_limit               12711  13 
xt_tcpudp              12603  18 
rfcomm                 42523  0 
bluetooth             209256  10 bnep,rfcomm
xt_addrtype            12635  4 
parport_pc             32688  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
uvcvideo               76749  0 
xt_state               12578  14 
videobuf2_core         32851  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120309  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12860  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13368  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
ip6table_filter        12815  1 
ip6_tables             27207  2 ip6t_rt,ip6table_filter
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12665  0 
joydev                 17457  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32007  1 
nf_conntrack_broadcast    12589  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77876  1 
nf_nat_ftp             12649  0 
nf_nat                 25254  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14480  9 nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv4         12729  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
snd_hda_intel          33491  7 
snd_hda_codec         134212  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
nf_conntrack_ftp       13359  1 nf_nat_ftp
arc4                   12529  2 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
nf_conntrack           82633  8 nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ftp
iptable_filter         12810  1 
snd_pcm                96580  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
ip_tables              26995  1 iptable_filter
coretemp               13400  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30512  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlwifi               390922  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
lp                     17759  0 
kvm_intel             136907  0 
snd_seq                61521  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
psmouse                95552  0 
parport                46345  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
x_tables               29711  13 ip6t_REJECT,xt_hl,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,xt_LOG,xt_limit,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_state,ip6table_filter,ip6_tables,iptable_filter,ip_tables
samsung_laptop         14532  0 
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
serio_raw              13215  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
lpc_ich                17061  0 
video                  19335  1 samsung_laptop
kvm                   418206  1 kvm_intel
snd                    74638  24 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
mac80211              544104  1 iwlwifi
soundcore              15047  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18484  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
microcode              22803  0 
cfg80211              202470  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
binfmt_misc            17500  1 
sky2                   58111  0
```

Can anyone help?  I have tried installing the driver from ati but when I run the aticonfig --intial I get the following:

```
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

The graphic modes were fine when I first installed but I tried to install the fglrx module and it all went pear shaped.  I suspect that if I delete xorg.conf it will go back to normal but I want to have the ati command center.

Thanks,

J.

Comment: See the 2nd answer to this question, it will explain http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513

Answer (score 2):

See if this page helps you any:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 12.10 you should take a look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225631/ouch-laptop-running-super-hot-after-12-10-upgrade) which describes a similar problem and the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517) offered [in this other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10).

The solution above worked for me and is as follows;

"For those who have hybrid systems (ATI/intel) and fglrx has stopped working in 12.10, then the problem might be like the one described here (fglrx incompatibility with the recent version of the intel driver): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1068404

What I would suggest would be

Remove all the fglrx* packages:

sudo apt-get purge fglrx*

Add my PPA in your repositories list:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrikos

Update your package information:

sudo apt-get update

Update the fglrx and intel drivers:

sudo apt-get install fglrx xserver-xorg-video-intel

Don't forget to enable the fglrx driver

sudo aticonfig --initial --force"

Good luck.