# High temperature in a AMD Radeon HD4000/3000 series after upgrade

Tags: kernel, radeon

I was running 12.04 with Unity 3D for 6 months; my laptop ran almost silently and cool enough to hold on my lap with ~4 hours of battery life. I updated to 12.10 and switched to the Gnome 3 Shell. Now my computer gets too hot to hold on my lap, the fan is constantly running on full blast, and I have about 45 minutes of battery life. The behavior is consistent between battery power and A/C power. This is the output of `sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0 
Adapter: Virtual device 
temp1:        +84.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +84.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) 
Core 0:         +74.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) 
Core 1:         +72.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) 
Core 2:         +75.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) 
Core 3:         +84.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100 
Adapter: PCI adapter 
temp1:        +76.0°C
```

I have an HP Pavilion dv6, Intel i7, AMD Radeon graphics. Please let me know if you need additional information.

What could be different between these two Ubuntu editions that caused such a drastic change?

**Edit 1:**

Per @Paul's suggestion, I ran `htop` to try to narrow down the problem. Here is the result!

[image: Left side of terminal]

(left side of terminal)

[image: Right side of terminal]

(right side of terminal)

This is about 10 minutes after boot-up, `htop`, `yakuake`, and a `chrome` page with 1 tab opened to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225631/laptop-runs-hot-after-12-10-upgrade) are all that I have manually opened. The most taxing program to the CPU is `htop` itself. I think that the problem must lie elsewhere; my temps are already up to ~65C for the CPU and ~69C for the GPU, with nearly 0% CPU usage.

**Edit 2:**

As requested by @psusi, here is the output of 2 tabs from `powertop` (changed my colors for readability):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Again, all I am manually running is one `google-chrome` tab and a `yakuake` terminal. I am fairly new to `powertop`, so I am unsure how to interpret this. Let me know if you need info from the other tabs.

**Edit 3:**

I was having battery issues with 12.04 and fixed those by changing some lines in `/etc/default/grub`; credit [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67965/laptop-minimal-power-consumption-tweaks).

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1"
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_aspm=force"

I have kept these lines the same after updating to 12.10. Do these look OK?

**Edit 4:**

@Arup Roy Chowdhury mentioned that my AMD drivers might not be installed correctly. I am currently using the following driver (output from `software-properties-gtk`):

[image]

Should I be using a proprietary driver instead? The gnome-shell seems to be running graphics acceleration OK with the open source one.

**Edit 5:**

@hazrpg I have posted the log files you requested to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/). Here is the [dmesg.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1421450/), [lspci.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1421456/), and [lsusb.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1421465/). See any issues?

**Edit 6:**

@Sepero Here are my idle temps. I am only running one terminal ~10 minutes after bootup.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +64.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +63.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

Core 0:         +62.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +60.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +60.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +63.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +68.0°C
```

Just opening `google-chrome` to paste this edit for a minute has raised those temperatures by a few degrees each. My computer was not in the 60s prior to the update.

**FIXED!!:**

Problem solved. Thank you to @DrA7 and @YellowApple to pointing me in the direction of graphics card problems. I found this [wonderful question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10) and implemented @Nick Andrik's solution. In a nutshell, installing the proprietary drivers (fglrx-updates) from ppa:andrikos solved the problem. I can now use ATI Catalyst to choose my power mode and which graphics card (Intel or AMD) I want to use. My temperatures are down to ~44 degrees and battery life is up to ~4 hours again. I also installed Jupiter, which improved battery and temperatures further.

The open source drivers for AMD seem to be getting better, however it looks like their support for hybrid graphics cards (like mine) is not quite up to spec. Use the proprietary drivers for now.

Comment: How about `powertop`?

Comment: @psusi See edits 2 and 3 above. Would additional tabs from `powertop` help?

Comment: Yes, Idle stats and Frequency stats would be helpful.

Comment: @psusi Idle Stats and Frequency Stats are added.

Comment: dang, you're pushing the limits there. try installing the `fancontrol` package.

Comment: Hrm.. the frequency stats seem to be broken because they don't add up to nearly 100%... other than that, nothing looks too out of the ordinary.

Comment: Could you please give us the output of the following (paste to paste.ubuntu.com): "dmesg > dmesg.log; lspci > lspci.log; lsusb > lsusb.log;". Run without quotes, and find the files dmesg.log, lspci.log, and lsusb.log and paste them to that site. Put them in separate pastes if you can. I ask, because it seems you have some missing device drivers according to the info I see above.

Comment: @hazrpg I have posted the logs you requested. Upon second look, those "bad" USB tunables in `powertop` were due to an external USB drive I had in. I have updated the question with a new screenshot. I am still getting hot without that USB drive. `

Comment: @Sepero I went from `12.04 + Unity 3D` to `12.10 + Gnome 3 Shell`. I have updated the original question to include that information. Looking into pure idle temps now.

Comment: @Sepero See edit 6 for idle temps.

Comment: @OP: You should post this whole Q and your problem on the Ubuntu bugtracker. It seems like a huge regression.

Comment: @dinkelk, heh seems someone else helped you out before me. Congrats. But yeah, had I have come back sooner I would have noticed that you seem to have 2 graphics cards and suggested you used the proprietary drivers too (based on the lspci.log stuff).

Comment: Too much proof; let's vote down!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that it must be related to your video drivers.

Could it be that while using 12.04 you had the proprietary drivers installed but somehow switched to open source after upgrade?

Your problems match mine exactly and I have 12.10 installed on a HP Pavillion G7, with i5 and Intel HD3000/Radeon 6850 graphics hybrid.
I would assume that you are currently only using the Intel GPU and that is what is causing your problems. (Yet somehow your GPU temperature reading is the highest...)

I have yet to find a better solution than applying the Grub parameters you described in Edit 3, along with installing [Jupiter](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter) and setting it to "Power Saving".

**EDIT;**

Am currently for the first time since upgrading to 12.10 able to display Unity using fglrx after applying the solution you suggested in "FIXED!!", that is, "installing the proprietary drivers (fglrx-updates) from ppa:andrikos" without any further modifications.

Answer (score 9):

### Background: ATI PowerPlay vs Open source drivers

Many people are experiencing drawbacks on graphics performance and powersaving capabilities after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10. This is ascribed to the lack of driver support for X Server 1.13 that comes with the Ubuntu upgrade forcing people to use open source drivers or downgrade to previous versions of X Server. Although the open source drivers has been improved vastly in recent years they are not up to the level of the power management of PowerPlay supplied with the proprietary ATI drivers.

A few things to notice here for others who might be reading:

This only affects HD 4xxx graphics cards and below. Users of later cards should have no problem using the ATI Catalyst drivers. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10) for known issues though.

### Possible solutions

I have yet to find fully automated solutions that works at the level of ATI PowerPlay GPU management. However I did stumple accross some interesting tools and tricks that essentially enables you to control the GPU profiles.

**Downgrade to previous version of X Server and install Catalyst ATI drivers.**
Perhaps the most straight forward method is to not use X Server 1.13 at all. Use [Tomasz Makarewicz's ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Emakson96/+archive/fglrx) for downgrading X Server to 1.12 and install fglrx-legacy catalyst drivers. The success to which these packages solves the problems [are mixed](http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/#comment-688951855) so you should be mindful about doing this.

To add the repository for the packages type in

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
```

Update and upgrade the system to apply the downgrade of X server:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and finally install the legacy driver

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

If you wish to uninstall these packages and get back to the Xorg drivers you need to remove the repository and return to the standard version of X server. This can be done using ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:makson96/fglrx
```

which will automatically remove packages associated with target repository. Simply reboot and you should have the Xorg drivers installed again.

**Manual control of the power method**

The Xorg drivers provides [features](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature) for controlling the power methods of Radeon graphics. Dynamic control should be enabled by default, letting the system mange the power profiles itself. To view the current state of power control you can run

```
sudo cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/graphics/fb0/device/power_method
```

This will show either dynpm (automatic control) or profile (manual control). If you wish to control the power profiles yourself you may set it to profile by

```
sudo echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/graphics/fb0/device/power_method
```

and provide a valid profile using

```
sudo echo mid > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/graphics/fb0/device/power_profile
```

Possible options are

```
default
auto
low
mid
high
```

To re-enable the dynamic power management simply run

```
sudo echo dynpm > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/graphics/fb0/device/power_method
```

**Radeon Power Profile Manager**

Gnome 3 users might be interested in the [Radeon Power Profile Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/356/radeon-power-profile-manager/) extension, controlling the GPU profiles from the Xorg drivers. I admit I haven't tested this tool myself, but it is worth a try.

[image: Gnome 3 Radeon Power Profile Manager Extension]

Comment: Thank you for the verbose answer. Installing `fglrx-updates` from ppa:andrikos (see my final edit) ended up solving my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that 12.10 (and Ubuntu-based distros based on 12.10, like Linux Mint 14) tend to run really hot with open-source drivers on AMD/ATI GPUs for some reason.  Installing the proprietary driver helps - or at least it helped me.  Go ahead and give that a try.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Installing the proprietary helped fix the problem (see my edit).

Answer (score 1):

I had high t due to high uncalled CPU usage. Somehow installing bumbleebee paired with installing jupiter reduced CPU usage and t!

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable sudo add-apt-repository
>
> ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic

Comment: This seems like a reasonable patch to my system. However, this does not help me get to the root of the problem. I never needed `bumblebee + jupiter` with 12.04. I should not need it after. I think there is something else going on here.

Comment: He is using an ATI card. As far as I know, Bumblebee is used for NVidia GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

The high temperature is most likely due to a heavy load either on the CPU or on the GPU or both.

In your case it seems both are quite hot. I would recommend narrowing down the problem by checking what is using your resources. Issuing the command `top` or better yet `htop` in a terminal, then sorting the processes by CPU usage might help you find the task causing the high temperatures.

top is already installed by default. Personally I find htop much more userfriendly though. Hit F6 to sort by CPU with htop.

To install it: `sudo apt-get install htop`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! However, I could not find a problem using `htop`. See "edit 1" above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with both Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 on my Sony Vaio SVE1512W1ESI laptop with an AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M card. Fan was running all the time and the sensors tool showed temperatures in 60s (started with 56-57 and then went to 67-68 with e.g. browser opened).

I installed proprietary drivers from System **Settings** --> **Additional Drivers** but didn't help. Finally, I installed proprietary driver from [AMD's website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) and it fixed the problem.

I followed the following simple steps to install it (as described in the installation instructions manual found on the same webpage):

1. `sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64.run`
2. Choose first option (`Install driver XX on X.Org XX`) and then choose `Automatic`
3. `sudo /usr/bin/aticonfig --initial`
4. Reboot