# AMD proprietary drivers on ubuntu 12.10 only see desktop

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, intel, proprietary

Hi I've been stuck with this problem and I hope someone can help.

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 64bit on my system.

- Asus amd 6850
- Intel celeron g530
- 8GB ram
- Motherboard: GA-H61MA-D3V (rev. 2.0)

I installed ubuntu fine but when I install the proprietary drivers all I can see on reboot is the background.

I tried following this guide but it did not work http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioMeSCoyYng

AMD Catalyst:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Reboot and then Install proprietary drivers via Software Sources.

I'm also getting errors regarding compiz and unity, with xubuntu the drivers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225631/ouch-laptop-running-super-hot-after-12-10-upgrade) which describes a similar problem and the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517) offered [in this other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10).

That solution worked for me and is as follows:

> For those who have hybrid systems (ATI/intel) and fglrx has stopped
>   working in 12.10, then the problem might be like the one described
>   here (fglrx incompatibility with the recent version of the intel
>   driver):
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1068404
>
> What I would suggest would be
>
> Remove all the fglrx* packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
> ```
>
> Add my PPA in your repositories list:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrikos
> ```
>
> Update your package information:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Update the fglrx and intel drivers:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install fglrx xserver-xorg-video-intel
> ```
>
> Don't forget to enable the fglrx driver:
>
> ```
> sudo aticonfig --initial --force
> ```