# High temperatures in ubuntu 12.10 (64)

Tags: nvidia, temperature

To the experienced, I think reach dangerous temperatures in Laptop with Ubuntu. The version is 12.10 and the extras just installed `lm-sensors` and `java`.

```
root @ ubuntu :/ home / ricardo # sensors acpitz-virtual-0
 Adapter: Virtual device
 TEMP1: +79.0 ° C (crit = +99.0 ° C)
 temp2: +29.8 ° C (crit = +99.0 ° C)

 coretemp-isa-0000
 Adapter: ISA adapter
 Physical id 0: +90.0 ° C (high = +86.0 ° C, crit = +100.0 ° C)
 Core 0: +90.0 ° C (high = +86.0 ° C, crit = +100.0 ° C)
 Core 1: +88.0 ° C (high = +86.0 ° C, crit = +100.0 ° C)
```

This Windows walks in their 50 º C, but linux is a heater that melts the battery quickly.
The Laptop is a Samsung 300v3a s03pt, i5 second generation, intel hd 3000 and nvidia does not interest me install gt 520m.
I tried that already has linux driver optimized.
What can I do? The bios it is updated, the fan runs at background, and yes it is only on linux.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you are having issues with that Nvidia device you don't care about.  Take a look at this:

Community Wiki: [OUCH! Laptop running SUPER HOT after 12.10 upgrade!](https://askubuntu.com/q/225631/88546)

Basically the graphics card is a primary source of system heat along with the system processor.  Assume any GPU processors or embedded GPU processors are a source of heat in most cases and realize most systems have more than one GPU which combined produce more heat through the system than the processor.

Also refer to the linked article for attempts at cooling the main processor as well.

Comment: ricardo@ubuntu:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +67.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +81.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +70.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +80.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

Answer (score 0):

Not updated, but it was installed again.
I installed the nvidia drivers as follows:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa: bumblebee / stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-bumblebee bumblebee

Then to test the terminal writes:

glxgears <- for Intel board

optirun glxgears <- for nvidia card

**The temperature of the CPU is much higher than gpu**

ricardo@ubuntu:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +67.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +81.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +70.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +80.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)