# Waiting for required medium software center

Tags: software-center

I'm trying to install the proprietary AMD drivers through **Software Sources**. I tick the box for `fglrx-updates`, and it says applying changes and fills 10% of a progress bar. It then sites there for hours (I left the computer unattended).

Trying to get this process to finish, I found that the Ubuntu software center progress tab display a message reading:

> Applying Changes: Waiting for required medium

What in the world does that mean and how can I get it to move on?

Comment: In a word, I'm an idiot. This message meant I couldn't swap to the driver I wanted because it wasn't installed yet. I should have actually followed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10

instead of skipping the step where you install fgrlx-updates and fgrlx-amdcccle-updates.