# Ubuntu desktop 12.10 64-bit, icons don't show

Tags: unity, 12.10, ati, compiz, fglrx

Recently I had problems with fglrx cause I have an ATI card, if I install the privative drivers from the Ubuntu repo, I get no Unity launch bar cause the drivers are not compatible with the new Xorg.

So, I installed manually the new beta drivers following the reponse of **ryanpcmcquen** in this question:
[Can't install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10)

Because I have also a 5670 card.

Everything work, I get now from info:

```
jdsampayo@jdsampayo-M61PME-S2:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5670
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11995 Compatibility Profile Context
```

The problem is that when Unity starts I don't get any icons in *desktop* and right mouse clicks there also do nothing, but I get the *Unity bar* working.

If I launch ccsm and I disable the Unity plugin (bar dissapears) and reenable it, the bar reappears and icons in desktop and right click mouse in desktop works as expected.

Is there any way to do this automatically? (disable and enable Unity plugin)

Because I must do this each login to make the desktop work.

*PD. I tried to put this info in the question I refer, but I have no reputation in askubuntu and couldn't find a way to add any info or comments in questions.*

Comment: This happened to me, and I managed to install `fglrx-updates`. That worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jorge

First, I recommend you to update ubuntu to a new version, it could be  15.04 because the drivers have better support.

Then go to the terminal and do What @10robinho told you. Because that command install the most recent drivers.

Comment: Thanks! I no longer have this problem but will mark this response as  the answer because it worked for 10robinho!