# intel/ati hybrid graphics card query

Tags: hybrid-graphics

I am using 12.04 and i followed this [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450/) to install the intel/ati(3000/6490m) hybrid graphics on my ubuntu. I desparately want to try 12.10 and the coming 13.04 and when i see there is no perfect solution to make the hybrid cards work i feel frustated. I have to wait months before the someone gives the solution. Can anyone tell me why there is no driver support for ati/intel cards and if they will be supported in future releases. I really want to upgrade the system. Is there any HOPE ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 12.10 and recently got a laptop with Intel/ATI Hybrid Graphics card. I'm quite happy with the default setup. The only problem I see is **too much power consumption when running on battery**. After trying many different ways of installing **proprietary drivers** in vain (the farthest I've got was a desktop without Unity and Metacity) I've found my best option might be using **vga_switcheroo** as explained this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Comment: Have You tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450/) ? It worked for me, on 12.04, I havn't tried on 12.10. If you havn't tried this yet then please read that post and all the comments(very helpful). I think they have sorted out the problem for 12.10.

Comment: After I entered the command **sudo aticonfig --initial -f** I got stuck with this error message: **PowerXpress error: '/usr/lib64/fglrx' must not be writable by group or others**. It doesn't matter whatever changes I make in file/folder permissions.

Comment: @Arin, thanks, I've finally managed to install the proprietary driver 13.3 beta version by simply downloading and running it, although I had to re-install the libgl1-mesa-glx package.

Comment: The only thing that has worked for me are the updates from the Andrikos PPA: http://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517