# Can't upgrade to ubuntu 12.10 - Radeon 7470M issue

Tags: 12.10, radeon

Firstly : Happy new year !

I have a HP DM4-3060ef and it works great with Ubuntu 12.04.
I'd like to use 12.10 for different reasons (its a little bit faster and I like webApps - even in a developer side) I've tried many times now to upgrade and it never works because the Radeon Graphics Card (7470M).

It seems that the fglrx drivers are not compatible with the new xorg version. I tried to install AMD 12.11 beta drivers but I can't make them work. I'm really surprised to not find many people complainig about this issue with AMD drivers online. Has someone managed to make this card work in 12.10?

Thanks for your help.

Dominique.

*PS : Sorry for my english ... I'm a french guy :-)*

Comment: You could try the solution outlined here; http://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to askubuntu. I don't know how you are upgrading.

So here is my suggestion,

1. Remove `fglrx` drivers from current system.

   ```
   sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
   sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
   ```
2. Update ubuntu.
3. Reinstall drivers using this guide [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124292/35775)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm upgrading with the update tools from ubuntu. I had installed amd drivers in 12.04 with jockey-gtk. After upgrading i tried with amd 12.10 drivers and 12.11beta