# I get a black screen after logging in

Tags: login

The cursor is still there though.

Startup is fine, it still gets to the login screen, but as soon as I press enter when I enter my password to log in, the screen turns black, and nothing happens.

Note (if it helps): I just installed it, and haven't been able to log in yet, so it's not a problem with software I installed. (It's 12.10) Also, I installed it from a disc, not Wubi.

Comment: What kind of video card do you have?  It sounds like you need a different video driver.

Comment: ATI Radeon HD 5670. How can I install a different driver?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a guide to install a new driver.  There's information out there for your specific video card.  To get into a command-line only interface during bootup, I believe holding `shift` will do it.

Here's a few links I found:

[Can't install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS9Nmet_sqQ

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI