# How can I make an AMD/Intel switchable graphics system work?

Tags: 12.04, ati, intel-graphics, hp, switchable-graphics

I used my HP Probook 4530s (6490m + HD3000 graphics) laptop with Ubuntu 12.04, but its battery life is too much poor. It lasted one and half hour whereas in Windowns7 it lasted 3-4 hours.

For using outside with unplugged, I decide to use ATI switchable graphics. I have already installed Catalyst properly, then applied [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450).

There were no errors while following them and my battery then lasted 3-4 hours. But when I rebooted my laptop, Ubuntu loading screen was stuck and not responding could not access login page. When I switched off the ATI via the computer BIOS I was able to boot.

For Windows7  I must to use ATI because of gaming so I don't want to have to change that every time in the BIOS.

What can I do about to make switchable graphics work properly?

Comment: check this link once - http://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working

Comment: I see that you have 12.04 but I found my solution in here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10