# How to install the proprietary AMD graphic driver(fglrx) correctly via the AMD website?

Tags: 14.04, ati, software-installation, fglrx, catalyst

> **This question currently aims to describe how to install the proprietary drivers for AMD graphic cards from the AMD website. Refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) question for other ways to install it. Please don't get misled by the description below.**

The question here was actually this :

*How to backup all software(include ones not installed from Software centre) including proprietary graphics drivers?*

This was the description provided when the immediately above question was there:

*I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I want to move on to 13.10(the latest version of Ubuntu, I suppose). But it seems upgrading takes lot of time. So I want to do a fresh install of 13.10. If I do that I will be losing all the software and settings(as you know). So I have to backup all software including the non-software-centre ones. I dont know how to do that(I have never backed up before). I also want to backup my fglrx driver for my ATI Radeon 5570 HD graphic card because when I first installed 12.10 I had to undergo some pain getting that driver to work(by following the steps here: [Can't install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10) ) and I dont want to undergo that again. So help please!!
(P.S: I am a complete amateur. I have just been introduced to and been using Ubuntu for just 3 months. So please give easy to understand explanation(i.e) dont get too technical)*

By the comments provided below and by my experience I was able to learn a correct way to install the AMD graphic card driver. Therefore to help future vistors the question above was changed. The answer below(by myself) answers the current question.