# What video driver should I download?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, video, fglrx

I'm trying to install the ATI drivers for Ubuntu. When I run sudo lshw -c video it shows:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310]
   vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:41 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff
```

I try to follow the instructions found here: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)

But, when I get to http://support.amd.com/en-us/download it confuses me because I don't know exactly where to look up for my driver. Could somebody help me, please? I have a laptop, Toshiba Satellite C660D-16K, running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I don't know what categories to select. I tried several options but couldn't find what I was looking for. Or maybe I did found it, but I didn't know it was the right driver. Thank you in advance, and sorry for my English.

Comment: Are there any issues with the open source driver? What makes you believe the proprietary driver is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have an E-240 APU and a ATI Radeon 6310 HD graphics card in your laptop as I found from [this](http://www.toshiba.com.ro/discontinued-products/satellite-c660d-16k/) link by googling about your laptop. In the link to the AMD's support site which you have specified in your description to the question, I selected APU, Mobile APU, E-series APU and x86 in the list boxes respectively according to your laptop specs and the output of your terminal you provided above and then I got [this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86). I recommend that you install the latest beta driver(i.e) 14.3 LINUX Beta V1.0 driver as it is very recent. To do so follow the below steps:-

1. **Check the release notes of the driver**. It is very important.Though I have done so myself, I suggest you to check it before you install your driver. From what I saw, the driver seems to support the AMD Radeon 6000 HD series going by the release notes of the driver. But under the APU family compatibility the release notes dont seem to mention the E-240 series(which is your APU). So it is a bit suspicious. But I cant find any other driver. I would also suggest that you **check if your OS supports all the system requirements specified in the release notes**.
2. Then you might have to **follow the installer notes** for installing your driver.
3. For further details you may refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434986/how-to-install-amd-graphic-driver-correctly-in-ubuntu-13-10/435796#435796). It states the method to install the driver, what to do if things go wrong and also commands to check your system requirements. It states the method for 13.10 OS. But it may work on your OS too.

Comment: If you are running windows alongside Ubuntu 12.04 maybe you can install the auto detect software that AMD offers on that link you provided above, in your windows OS. That way you may get an idea about your graphic card driver and then download a similar driver for your Ubuntu OS. I also suggest you wait for more answers and then do the necessary for I am not an expert!

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice and I used the software AMD offers. When I ran the software it showed: "E Series APU", and that's all. So I managed to find the driver at ease now, because I knew what I was looking for. I managed to install the beta version :).