# Installing fglrx driver always fails

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, fglrx, opengl

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 and wanted to try some OpenGL programming. My laptop has switchable graphics technology (**Intel HD Graphics 4000** and **AMD Radeon HD 8570M**). I thought that it'd be better to install proprietary drivers and take advantage of OpenGL 4+ so first I installed the drivers by typing `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`, then I rebooted my pc. However, after boot, low-graphics error came up instead of login screen.

I didn't give up and tried searching google on my other computer. I tried almost everything possible, yet it still looks like my graphics is not being recognized.

It's worth noting that I have linux-headers installed and am using 64bit version of Ubuntu. Also, when I uninstall the fglrx driver, everything works fine again.

Here's what I already tried:

- Reinstalling the drivers (complete purge).
- Entering low-graphics mode and typing `amdconfig --initial`.
- Installing the newest drivers drivers from amd.com (I also tried beta drivers; no luck).
- I switched LightDM to GDM, still no luck (it completely broke my Ubuntu installation).

Thank you for any suggestion.

**EDIT:** By reading some log files I came to a conclusion that the greeter fails to start. I just don't know why.

**EDIT 2:** I installed GDM once again. Now it boots to console without showing any error. I tried to log in and type `startx` and it says `Caught signal 11 (Segmentation failed).`

Comment: Try this :http://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10/207270#207270

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. The low-resolution graphics error still comes up.

Comment: Mmmm...Then to solve low graphics error you can follow this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error Don't fail to see Jokerdino's answer there. It addresses your greeter issue.

Comment: I already check that. The problem is that `ubuntu-greeter` is already there.

Comment: Post your ' /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf '  file.

Comment: The 50-ubuntu.conf is almost empty. Here it is, anyway - http://pastebin.com/txu3tJ2F

Comment: Try adding this line to that file: greeter-session=unity-greeter BTW reconfigure lightdm before trying it.

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't work. Linux is great, there's just always something that prevents me from using it to its full potential...

Comment: Uhh... I have moved this to chat and pinged you in the chatroom... weren't you notified?