# 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade screen goes black after 2-5 minutes

Tags: upgrade, crash, amd-graphics

I upgrade to 16.04 LTS (from 14.04 LTS) yesterday. I have two monitors, and when I rebooted after the upgrade, I could see the X windows and Gnome in both monitors. However, they were not two separate displays: they were **cloned.** I had a key combination (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) that worked in separating the two monitors when this happened on boot in 14.04, but it doesn't work anymore. It only shows numbers over each display.

Then after 2 minutes or so, **the monitors went black,** and I had no mouse or keyboard access anymore.  The computer ran, rather high, with the fan blasting away, but I could do nothing.  I had to kill it with power button.

1. I tried booting with one monitor (the second unplugged from the computer), and
2. I switched to `tty1` after booting (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>) to see if it was Gnome or something.

Neither helped.

**I have two machines hooked to my monitor/keyboard/mouse** with a KVM switch, and this was connected, and the other machine was on while doing the upgrade.

I have killed the machine the hard way now several times, and the system displayed some `fsck`-related messages on boot. One error message appeared regarding the video card: `No UMS support in radeon module.`

Once, when booting with just the right monitor, I got a popup window with the message:

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors, none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 618
CRTC 618: trying mode 1400x1050 @ 77HZ with output at 1600x1200 @ 77Hz (pass 0)
[...]
```

While I was using Ubuntu 14.04, I [installed a driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10) for the video card that helped to reduce the temperature and the fan noise.

My system has the following specs:

- Dell Studio XPS 7100
- AMD Phenom II X6 1045T Processor
- 8 GB RAM
- ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series video card

How can I fix the issue without reinstalling?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do you have the fglrx driver installed? Or are you using the open source one?

Comment: Thank you, Andrea, for answering!  I booted the machine into recovery mode and typed fglrxinfo on the command line and it said this command is unknown.  So I assume I do not have the proprietary driver from AMD.  Is there another way to find out?

Comment: I see. «While I was using Ubuntu 14.04, I installed a driver for the video card» Do you recall which driver you installed? Can you check if it's still installed?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but back in March I sent myself an email with a link to a page that told how to install the fglrx driver.  I believe this is what I must have done.  I did it with synaptic package manager, and I just checked it on my machine, and it does not show up as installed in synaptic.

Comment: The link is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10.  And the subject line of my email was "cooling the video card ubuntu"

Comment: Please update the Q with the output of `ls -R /etc/X11/xorg*` and `grep -C 3 nomodeset /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43465/discussion-between-excyberlabber-and-andrea-lazzarotto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a lot of help from Andrea Lazzarotto (thanks, Andrea!), but in the end I found the answer myself. I searched for "No UMS support in radeon module" on google.  It turned up this link:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166037

which referred to the grub config.  So I ran the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and saw that it referred to my radeon card:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"
```

I removed the reference to the modeset, per the post listed above, so it read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

After editing the grub config, you must run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This saves the config changes in the file itself.  I did this and then rebooted.  This fixed the problem with the black screen/crash, and it also fixed the problem with the dual screens being cloned.